# draggable specific class which is a subclass of UIImageView

Tags: xcode

I have create a class Box which is a subclass of UIImageView.

In my program, I want to make the Box to be the only draggable object in the main view controller.

Here is my code:

BoxViewController.m

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    target = [[Box alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];
    [self.view addSubView:target];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch view] == target){
          CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
          target.center = location;
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event];
}
```

I think the condition is not working, but I have tried isKindOfClass. Both didn't work. What is the solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you set the userInteractionEnabled of your target to be YES?

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    target.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(location.x, location.y);
}
```